# Preserve text style when changing Text view text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a Text View with attributed text, with some style, set in Xcode utilities pan. Basically, a font, a size, and an alignement.

Then programmatically I change text of the view:

self.myView.text = "New text"

It does change the text, but discard all style of the text and use a default style.

I tried self.myView.attributedText = "New text" but got a protocol conformance issue.

What's the correct strategy to deal with this ?
Is there a way to inject the new text while preserving style ?
Or should I reset style manually each time I change text ?

(please answer in swift if possible)

Comment: Create a new `NSAttributedString` with the desired text and formatting. Then assign that to the `attributedText` property of the text view.

Comment: thanks you can create an answer and i'll select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to create an `NSAttributedString` with the desired text and formatting (font and text alignment).

Then assign the attribute string to the text field's `attributedText` property.